# NoSuchMethodError ConstantExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression when adding jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

After adding jetpack compose to my app as described in:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/compose-in-existing-ui
I see the following error when building:

```
Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.constants.evaluate.ConstantExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression$default(Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/constants/evaluate/ConstantExpressionEvaluator;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/psi/KtExpression;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/BindingTrace;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/types/KotlinType;ZILjava/lang/Object;)Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/constants/CompileTimeConstant;
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.stubs.ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.getConstantValue(ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.kt:808)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.stubs.ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.convertPropertyInitializer(ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.kt:775)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.stubs.ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.convertField(ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.kt:738)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.stubs.ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.convertField$default(ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.kt:678)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.stubs.ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.convertClass(ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.kt:409)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.stubs.ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.convertTopLevelClass(ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.kt:202)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.stubs.ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.convert(ClassFileToSourceStubConverter.kt:147)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.generateKotlinSourceStubs(Kapt3Extension.kt:297)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:172)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:102)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$invokeExtensionsOnAnalysisComplete(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:108)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:118)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:85)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:517)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:508)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:508)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:188)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:154)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:76)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:227)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit$default(CLITool.kt:222)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:214)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:271)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
```

Comment: Can you tell us what Kotlin plugin version you are using?

Comment: I have the same error, plugin version is 1.5.21. Probably @ligi you have resolved it in the meantime, please add a follow up?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when I was trying to migrate to the jetpack compose.

***make sure `kotlin gradle plugin` , `kotlin-stdlib` and `kotlinCompileVersion` are using the same version.***

`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin`

`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`

```
android {
    ....
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion composeVersion
        kotlinCompilerVersion xxxxxx // keep same here
    }
}
```

also if you have any problem when you are doing the migration for jetpack compose.

Google provides the code lab.

`git clone -b end https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs`

`main` branch is before migration `end` branch is after migration.

so you can compare you project setting with this code lab project setting.